# Is Here Maps API suitable for our needs?

Tags: here-api

We are planning to develop a new application that should offer:

- Android-capable
- Turn by turn with voice navigation
- Offline maps (and perhaps routing?)
- Satellite maps
- Truck issues

As fas as I can see, all of the requirements (but the offline routing) is included in different Here Maps developer plans. Nevertheless, I still have some questions:

- On their web (https://developer.here.com/plans/api/consumer-mapping), there are two main divisions (API plan and Mobile SDS plans). Which one is better for me and what is the difference?. I mean, it seems clear that I should go for the mobile plans, but not sure if this will be limiting my development in the future.
- There appear no pricing options for the Mobile SDKs. We are planning to make the app available to our customers on a free basis and they will be charged for enhanced services. But seeing that API plans are based on a volume basis... how does the mobile plans work? (does it have any cost depending on the number of transactions too?).
- Finally, customized POI are the main advantage of our app and is closed to other users (will no be made publicly available). Does the Here api include the option to add our POIs coming from another (ous) database on the fly?.

Thanks in advance,

Jose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn by turn guidance will be only available via the (Premium) MobileSDK. Via REST APIs you can get routing, but not TbT voice guidance. Also Offline is only avaiulable via the Premium MobileSDK. Beside this, the native MobileSDK offers native vectorbased map rendering, when you use the REST APIs you would need to use the raster tiles. So in a nutshell: if you target Mobiles, you should definitely go with the MobileSDK. If you need any feature that's only available via web APIs (platform extensions, isoline routing, and some more), you can still combine these web APIs with the MobileSDK.

Pricing depends on your usecases, so you should discuss your usecase with HERe Sales: https://developer.here.com/contact-us?interest=mobile-sdk#contact-sales

Customized POIs is quite general, but of course you can load datasets from your servers and show them as POIs on the map, but you could also use the Platform Extension CLE, that also allows you to search within your dataset and is seamless integrated in the MobileSDK already.

Comment: Great, clarifying response. Thanks a lot.